# Find epipolar lines from fundamental matrix

Tags: projective-space, svd

I have two sets of 2D points and a matching between them (correspond to the same 3D points captured on two photographs). I found a fundamental matrix F.

I would like to find epipolar lines. I.e. in each photo, I want to draw a line from each point to the coordinate of the opposite camera projected to that photo. How do I find a 2D coordinate of a camera? Or any second point on each epipolar line?

I found only implementations, which call epipolarLine() in Matlab, or computeCorrespondEpilines() in OpenCV. But I would like to compute it myself without any libraries. I can already compute singular value decomposition.

The F is

```
 0.0000076735   0.0000065266  -0.0026484181
-0.0000077379   0.0000190241   0.0003274198
-0.0024171562  -0.0038670395   1.0000000000
```

and one matched pair is $231.9210,  100.3261$ and $289.8867,   29.6767$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can find the answer to this in any standard reference, such as Hartley and Zisserman’s *Multiple View Geometry In Computer Vision*, chapter 9.

The fundamental matrix $\mathtt F$ maps a point to its corresponding epipolar line in the *other* image. Thus, the epipolar line in the second image of a point $\mathbf x$ in the first image is $\mathbf l'=\mathtt F\mathbf x$ and, going the other way, $\mathbf l=\mathtt F^T\mathbf x'$. The epipoles themselves are right and left null vectors, respectively, of $\mathtt F$, i.e., $\mathtt F\mathbf e=0$ and $\mathtt F^T\mathbf e'=0$.

Comment: Of course, I have seen it many times. When I multiply a matrix F by a point (988,292,1), I get (-0.00109, 0.00136, 0.5521) - this should be an eipipolar line in the opposite image. But what do these three numbers mean? How do I convert it to a 2D line?

Comment: @IvanKuckir https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homogeneous_coordinates#Line_coordinates_and_duality. You should take the time to learn the basics of using homogeneous coordinates if you’re going to be working with this stuff.

Comment: I learned the basics of projective spaces, but I never worked with lines :/ So after multiplying F\*x I get a line (-0.00021399, 0.000441, 0.05144), which I mark as (s,t,u). By definition, points of a line satisfy s\*x+t\*y+u\*z=0. To compute the line at x=0, I set x to 0, z to 1. So y = (0-s\*x-u\*z) / t . In my case, such epipolar lines cross near the middle of the image, which is a wrong result. Am I computing it correctly?

Comment: could you please help me with it? I am really lost and and I don't know anybody who could help me, I can not find an answer online.

Comment: @IvanKuckir I’d go back to your original data and double-check how you’re computing the fundamental matrix. When I compute $\mathbf x'\mathtt F\mathbf x$ for your matrix and point pair I get a value near either 0.003 or -0.004 (it’s not clear from your question which point belongs to which image). Compared to the magnitude of the entries of $\mathtt F$, this is not very close to zero. Note that your $\mathtt F$ is nonsingular, which will be the case most of the time with real-world data, so to compute epipoles you’ll need to find singular vectors that correspond to the least singular value.

Comment: You are right, my Fundamental matrix is wrong. I used an implementation of 8-point algorithm I found on GitHub which is wrong. There are so many wrong implementations of popular algorithms on GitHub, I wish there was a way to make authors delete them.